# pygame.mixer with USB soundcard causes (snd_pcm_recover) below 48000 Hz

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, usb, alsa

I have created a Python program to play a song when a button is pressed. I am using a USB sound card and `pygame.mixer` to load songs and play them randomly when the button is pressed. The songs are 16-bit little-endian signed WAV files at 44100 Hz (but I don't think this matters).

OS: Raspbian ([Debian 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_timeline) (Jessie))

Hardware: [Raspberry Pi Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Hardware)

When I initialize the mixer at 44100 Hz like so:

```
pygame.mixer.init(44100,-16,2,2048)
```

I get the following error printed many times when I run my program:

> ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred

I get this before I even play any songs.

However, if I initialize at 48000 Hz, I do not get the `underrun occurred` message. But my files play back at 48000 Hz! So they are faster and at higher frequency.

Any clues as to why this happens and how I can fix it? I will accept workarounds using other packages to play the files.

Comment: Have you tried a bigger buffer size?

Comment: Tried it at 4096 and 8192, same exact results. Seems to have no effect. What exactly IS the buffer?

Comment: Have you tried aplay command to play the song.

Comment: Yes, aplay works fine from the terminal.